# Data manipulation startdate enddate python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a promotion description dataset with the information about various promotions running and their start date-end date:

```
promo        item      start_date      end_date 

Buy1-get 1     A        2015-01-08    2015-01-12

Buy1-get 1     A        2015-02-16    2015-02-20

Buy1-40% off   B        2016-05-08      2016-05-09
```

Now I want to organise my data for subsequent analysis such that I have only single variable date with promo information for it.

```
date            item       Promo

2015-01-08       A         Buy1-get 1 

2015-01-09       A         Buy1-get 1 
2015-01-10       A         ......
2015-01-11       ....
2015-01-12

2015-02-16       A         Buy1-get 1 
2015-02-17       A         Buy1-get 1 
2015-02-18       ....      .......
2015-02-19       .....

..........
2016-05-09       B         Buy1-40% off
```

Any help would be  really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) all `Series`s created by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) with [`itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) columns `promo` and `item`:

```
df1 = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,
                           pd.date_range(r.start_date,r.end_date)) for r in df.itertuples()])
        .reset_index()
df1.columns = ['date','idx']
df1 = df1.set_index('idx')
df1 = df1.join(df[['item','promo']]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
         date item         promo
0  2015-01-08    A    Buy1-get 1
1  2015-01-09    A    Buy1-get 1
2  2015-01-10    A    Buy1-get 1
3  2015-01-11    A    Buy1-get 1
4  2015-01-12    A    Buy1-get 1
5  2015-02-16    A    Buy1-get 1
6  2015-02-17    A    Buy1-get 1
7  2015-02-18    A    Buy1-get 1
8  2015-02-19    A    Buy1-get 1
9  2015-02-20    A    Buy1-get 1
10 2016-05-08    B  Buy1-40% off
11 2016-05-09    B  Buy1-40% off
```

Another solution with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [groupby with resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-syntax-with-window-and-resample-operations):

```
df1 = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'idx'})
df1 = pd.melt(df1, id_vars='idx', value_vars=['start_date','end_date'], value_name='date')
        .set_index('date')
df1 = df1.groupby('idx')
         .resample('d')
         .ffill()
         .reset_index(level=1)
         .drop(['idx','variable'], axis=1)
df1 = df1.join(df[['item','promo']]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
         date item         promo
0  2015-01-08    A    Buy1-get 1
1  2015-01-09    A    Buy1-get 1
2  2015-01-10    A    Buy1-get 1
3  2015-01-11    A    Buy1-get 1
4  2015-01-12    A    Buy1-get 1
5  2015-02-16    A    Buy1-get 1
6  2015-02-17    A    Buy1-get 1
7  2015-02-18    A    Buy1-get 1
8  2015-02-19    A    Buy1-get 1
9  2015-02-20    A    Buy1-get 1
10 2016-05-08    B  Buy1-40% off
11 2016-05-09    B  Buy1-40% off
```

Answer (score 1):

You could let the non-date columns take on the index-axis as they would vary in the direction w.r.t any changes made to the date cols. This would be handy during the grouping operation.

Specifying `append=True` helps to keep track of the index which the original `DF` had before. `stack` them so that the *start_date* and the *end_date* fall below one another.

```
mi_ser = df.set_index(['promo', 'item'], append=True).stack()
grouper = mi_df.index.get_level_values(0)
```

Construct a new `Series` having it's values and indices same as the values present in our previous multi-index series object.

Perform `groupby` w.r.t  first index level and resample the values according to daily frequency and choose any form of aggregation function compatible with `datetime` values. [Here, `first` is chosen]

```
s = pd.Series(mi_ser.values, mi_ser.values).groupby(grouper).resample('D').first()
idx, val = s.index.get_level_values(0), s.index.get_level_values(1)
```

Again, construct a new dataframe this time having it's values and indices as defined below.
Since the indices are aligned, we could `join` the two dataframes along them.

```
pd.DataFrame(val, idx, ['date']).join(df[['item', 'promo']]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't mind me.  I just wanted to `numpy`-fy this question/answer

```
day = int(60 * 60 * 24 * 1e9)

sd = df.start_date.values
ed = df.end_date.values
dd = ed - sd
ds = (dd / day).astype(int) + 1

sdays = ds.sum()
cdays = ds.cumsum()
rng = np.arange(sdays)
slc = np.roll(cdays % sdays, 1)
add = rng - rng[slc].repeat(ds)

d1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        promo=df.promo.values.repeat(ds),
        item=df.item.values.repeat(ds),
    ), pd.Index(sd.repeat(ds) + add * day, name='date'))

print(d1)

           item         promo
date                         
2015-01-08    A    Buy1-get 1
2015-01-09    A    Buy1-get 1
2015-01-10    A    Buy1-get 1
2015-01-11    A    Buy1-get 1
2015-01-12    A    Buy1-get 1
2015-02-16    A    Buy1-get 1
2015-02-17    A    Buy1-get 1
2015-02-18    A    Buy1-get 1
2015-02-19    A    Buy1-get 1
2015-02-20    A    Buy1-get 1
2016-05-08    B  Buy1-40% off
2016-05-09    B  Buy1-40% off
```